# Should we allow hardware questions?

Tags: discussion

So recently [this question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/4175) was closed as off-topic with the reason that "it is about a hardware replacement and ot *[sic]* about the Windows Phone O.S." (It's since been re-opened.)

The [Help Center](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't explicitly rule out questions about hardware, but I guess the argument could be made that questions do need to have *something* to do with Windows Phone, and that hardware questions therefore should be about how the hardware interacts with the OS.

So, how does everyone feel about this? Upvote/downvote answers to indicate support/opposition, or post your counterproposals below.

Comment: Have you typed wrongly "ot" near "[sic]" or did you copy from source and there were wrong? I don't remember.

Comment: I copied it from your comment, so it's verbatim.

Comment: Seems my question isn't closed anymore.

Comment: Yes. Hence the "It's since been re-opened" in my post.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say hardware questions like the one in question should be considered on-topic. The Help Center says you can ask about "Using your Windows Phone **device**" and "Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your **device**" (emphasis mine). A device includes both hardware and software, it doesn't make any sense to draw some sort of arbitrary line between the two.

Consider also other similar sites:

- [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) accepts questions about computer hardware and software
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) accepts questions about server hardware and software
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) accepts questions about Apple hardware and software
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) accepts questions about Android devices (I guess we copied our FAQ from them), and looking through some of the most popular topics they clearly don't disallow hardware-only questions

And so on, and so forth.

In addition to setting a completely different example compared to our sister sites, making hardware-only questions off-topic would also leave people with such questions nowhere to go.

Comment: Well, I must downvote since I disagree. To be ethical you must downvote mine too. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think different from `Indrek`.

I think some questions about hardware can be related with the Windows Phone O.S. but [some](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/4175) are completelly unrelated.

I'd say hardware questions like the one in question should be considered **Off-Topic**. The Help Center says you can ask about "**Using** your Windows Phone device" and "Trying to solve an error or other issue in **using** your device" (emphasis mine). I know a device includes both hardware and software, but I think we will end up receiving question by far not related with the purpose of this Q&A.

Some ficticional examples:

> How to replace a broken LCD?
>
> Where do I can buy replacement parts?
>
> Is it possible to install and external antenna in the device?

But some are related with the Windows Phone O.S:

> How can I restart the phone if it hang?
>
> How can I avoid phone unlock by pressing camera button?

Comment: Something like "Where do I can buy replacement parts?" would already be off-topic as "too-localized".